# Asociar un evento a distintos inputs files

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que pasa es que yo personalice un input file y tengo 5 inputs files mas lo que quiero saber es si hay una manera de hacer funcionar este evento sin crearlo otras 5 veces mas

```js
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("image1");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
const customTxt = document.getElementById("custom-text");

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  realFileBtn.click();
});

realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (realFileBtn.value) {
    customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value.match(
      /[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/
    )[1];
  } else {
    customTxt.innerHTML = "No se eligió archivo";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" class="imageFiles1" accept="image/*" hidden>
    <button type="button" id="custom-button"><i class="far fa-file-image"></i> Agregar foto</button>
    <span id="custom-text">No se eligió archivo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image2" class="imageFiles2" accept="image/*" hidden>
    <button type="button" id="custom-button2"><i class="far fa-file-image"></i> Agregar foto</button>
    <span id="custom-text2">No se eligió archivo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con `document.querySelectorAll()` y el evento `target`

ejemplo:

```js
// seleccionamos todos los button
// o cualquier elemento que se dese 
const realFileBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
// hacemos un loop para cada button que se encuentre
for(x of realFileBtn){
// asignamos a cada button el evento click puedes ser cualquier evento es a gusto
  x.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // el botton exacto que se le hace click
    let self = e.target;
    // el nodo anterior al button
    let input = self.previousSibling;
    // el nodo despues del button
    let span = self.nextSibling;
    console.log(self,input,span);
 });
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" class="imageFiles1" accept="image/*" hidden>
    <button type="button" id="custom-button"><i class="far fa-file-image"></i> Agregar foto</button>
    <span id="custom-text">No se eligió archivo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image2" class="imageFiles2" accept="image/*" hidden>
    <button type="button" id="custom-button2"><i class="far fa-file-image"></i> Agregar foto</button>
    <span id="custom-text2">No se eligió archivo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los elementos tiene una misma clase en en común puedes hacer uso de los selectores que te ofrece el documento,

### [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

El método `getElementsByClassName()` te va a devolver una [colección HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), que fácilmente puedes convertir a un array de Javascript, y con `forEach()` (o cualquier manera de iterar) puedes asignarle un evento a cada elemento.

```js
const file_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("files");
const files = Array.from(file_inputs);

files.forEach((file) => {
    file.addEventListener("change",() => alert("Evento!"));
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file2" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file3" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file4" class="files">
```

### [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

También puedes usar `document.querySelectorAll()`, este método de retorna todos los elementos que cumplan con la condición en string que se usa como parámetro. La diferencia a  `getElementsByClassName()` es que este método retorna un array de Javascript directamente.

```js
const files = document.querySelectorAll(".files");

files.forEach((file) => {
    file.addEventListener("change",() => alert("Evento!"));
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file2" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file3" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file4" class="files">
```

### [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Si los elementos de DOM no tiene una clase en común, puedes generar arrays con selectores para elementos únicos.

```js
let files = [];
for (let i of Array(5).keys()) files.push(document.getElementById(`file${i}`));
files = files.filter((file) => file != null);

files.forEach((file) => {
    file.addEventListener("change",() => alert("Evento!"));
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file2" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file3" class="files">

<input type="file" id="file4" class="files">
```

Saludos.